# Generating multiple lists of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

Thanks for the suggested solution. I have tried it and after some fiddling it works, however I am stuck on how to edit the generic 'List of Figures' heading to match my modified 'List of Plates' heading. This is how I changed the command you provided.

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{plate}{htpb}{plt}[chapter]
\floatname{plate}{Plate}
\renewcommand{\theplate}{\arabic{plate}}
\setcounter{plate}{1}
\newcommand{\listofplatesname}{\large List of Plates}
\newcommand{\listofplates}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listofplatesname}
\listof{plate}{\listofplatesname}}
```

[List of Plates heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b25r.jpg)

[List of Figures heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5lcF.jpg)

In my document (`book` class) I have two files in the backmatter containing illustrations. Using `\listoffigures` generates a combined list of figures. I would like to generate a separate list of illustrations for each file starting on its own page and with its own heading to put in the Table of Contents. Wondering if there is a simple solution for this?

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize \textbf{Plates} Colour Folios}
\input{chapterPLATES}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize \textbf{Figures} Comparative Illustrations}
\input{chapterFIGURES}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize References for Illustrations}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{ \large Figures}
{\small\listoffigures}
```

Comment: Are there mixtures of figures and plates in the same file?

Comment: there are packages for splitting TOCs, LOFs and LOTs to within each chapter. Is this what you want, or do you want it based on your inputfile?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `\newfloat` (package `float`) and using a new `\listofplates` command. The `\newfloat` command defines the plate counter automatically here.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{plate}{htpb}{plt}[chapter]
\floatname{plate}{Plate}

\usepackage{caption}


\newcommand{\listofplatesname}{List of Plates}
\newcommand{\listofplates}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listofplatesname}
  \listof{plate}{\listofplatesname}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listofplates
\clearpage

\blindtext[5]

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[5]

\chapter{The plates}

\begin{plate}
\caption{Foo plate}
\end{plate}


\begin{plate}
\caption{Foobar plate}
\end{plate}

\blindtext[10]


\end{document}
```

[image]